# How to encode utf_general_ci data to a human readable string?

Tags: java, php

I know this may seem very easy, but I have been stack because of this issue for days. The thing is am using `utf_general_ci` to store data that users save in different kinds of language. What I want is to display the data in human readable text here is an example.

The user enters the text 'ዝ' and, will be stored as utf_general_ci like 'á‹'.

I want to display the original text to the user which is 'ዝ' how can i do this. The data is stored in PHP MYSQL. I want to convert it JAVA or JSON FILE. What to do?

Here is the json code

```
   <?php

    header('Content-type:application/json; charset=utf8; http-equiv="Content-Type');

    $result = $db->query("SELECT * from movie");

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

        $output[] = array('MovieID' => $row['MovieID']);
        $output[] = array('Title' =>   $row['Title']);
    }

echo json_encode($output,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) ;
```

The insert statement is so simple and I defined the head of the web for as

```
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
```

Comment: UTF8 supports those characters. There is no need to encode or decode those characters.

Comment: But when i create the JSON file it displays ''á‹' not 'ዝ'

Comment: utf_general_ci is a collation. it has no relation to whatsover about your data storage format.

Comment: oh okay, but why is my json file showing me ''á‹' ? i want  'ዝ'. How can i make that happen?

Comment: you have wrong encoding specified somewhere. With the information you've given it's not possible to say where. In general, using UTF-8 everywhere is the first thing you should do when dealing with multilingual content.

Comment: @esi, pls help Here is my json file    <?php

header('Content-type:application/json; charset=utf8; http-equiv="Content-Type');

$result = $db->query("SELECT * from movie");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

    $output[] = array('MovieID' => $row['MovieID']);
    $output[] = array('Title' =>   $row['Title']);
}

echo json_encode($output,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE) ; </code>

Comment: add it to the question. add also the code how you insert the data to db

Comment: @esi, I updated the question u can find the code there. Thank you for the support. Pls give me a feed back

Comment: Oh my mistake i found my mistake guys. But thanks a lot guys @Daan